# Mongo 3.0.6 restore raw WT files

Tags: mongodb

we had a backup fail on the automated mongoexport/restore, as a secondary backup we also copy all the mongo wiretiger (.wt) files.  is there a way to restore from those?  I have tried to just copy them back into the data folder but it never seems to read it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of other meta data written outside *. Wt files. As with nmap1 we could only copy collection files,  with Wt this does not work.